# Deploying Oracle Forms 11g on standalone WebLogic Server

Tags: forms, weblogic

I set up the environment and everything, but I was wondering whether it is possible to install `WebLogic Server` alone and then configure it to run a `Forms application`, without having to install `Forms 11g` on the `server machine`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alone, Unfortunately oracle does not provide perfect solution for that....

This means not, it has no solution Here is 2 solutions..

Solution 1 :
You have to install both weblogic and form 11g on server machine.

Solution 2:
you can copy required files form development machine to server machine for alone server.

Choice is yours...

good luck!

Comment: But then what is difference between development machine and server machine.I mean to say I have done 1st solution but as a development point of view  .

Comment: look as per my knowledge,In case if you are using same machine for both development and deployment then you need to weblogic generic installer and if your going to use weblogic generic installer then your missing lots of functionality and by the way forms 11g does not allow other than  generic weblogic server.

Comment: What do you mean forms 11g does not allow other than generic weblogic server,if its true then how to use stand alone weblogic server.

Comment: Go with my 1st solution, just you have take care at one point during forms installation deselect development tools option other wise it will get error.and one more thing, here you can install any weblogic server not just generic  server.